# Is it possible to read an associative array value from layers deeper than the first one by passing its coordinate in a string?

Tags: php, arrays

Consider the following code sample which better illustrates my question:

```
<?php

$array['a']['b']['c'] = 'value of c';

$coordinates_for_c_key= "['a']['b']['c']";

print $array{$coordinates_for_c_key};

// Output: value of c
```

Is there a way to accomplish the above proposal?